# How to get a Lookup from nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, lookup

I have a nested dictionary from which I want to derive a Lookup. Example data of the dictionary is following:

```
var binary_transaction_model = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
binary_transaction_model.Add("123", new Dictionary<string, bool>(){{"829L", false},{"830L", true}});
binary_transaction_model.Add("456", new Dictionary<string, bool>(){{"829L", true},{"830L", false}});
binary_transaction_model.Add("789", new Dictionary<string, bool>(){{"829L", true},{"830L", true}});
```

This LINQ statement is working:

```
var cols = from a in binary_transaction_model
    from b in a.Value
    where b.Value == true
    group a.Key by b.Key;
```

It gives me an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String,String>>`. For lookup purposes I need this result as a Lookup data structure. How can I do this? How should a `ToLookup()` signature look like? (***Edit:*** I want to have a `Lookup<String,String>`.)

Comment: Could you please provide sample output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var cols = (from a in binary_transaction_model
            from b in a.Value
            where b.Value == true
            select new { aKey = a.Key, bKey = b.Key })
            .ToLookup(x => x.bKey, x => x.aKey);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Outstanding how fast I was assisted. I never thought about a `select new`...